# how to find user control's id in aspx page

Tags: asp.net, webusercontrol

I have an aspx web application in which 1 aspx page and 1 web user controls exist. I added 4 instances of the user control in aspx page. There is a remove button in user control which is used to remove the control from the aspx page. If I click on remove button of the user control, how can I find that which user control's remove button is clicked from the aspx page. Please let me know the solution...

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're trying to do this client-side you can reference the ID like this:

```
var removeButtonId = "<%=removeButton.ClientID %>";
```

---

If you've wired up a click event you can get it from the `sender` parameter like so:

```
void removeButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Button removeButton = sender as Button;
    string id = removeButton.ID;
}
```

Comment: I am doing this in codebehind and more over I have 4 instances of same user control in aspx page.

Comment: Id is returning the Button Id, however I need to get the ID of the usercontrol instance - (need to know which user control instance's button is clicked from main page)

Comment: what is the end goal? What are you ultimately trying to get at? The row the button was in so you can remove it? Try using `removeButton.ClientID` or `removeButton.UniqueID`

Comment: my goal is to delete the user control instance on click of the remove button.I placed the remove button in user control thinking each user control will have unique remove button so that I can remove the user control instance on click of instance's remove button, but not able to find the way to achieve this.....

Comment: If you're sure / don't do null-check, then you should use `cast`, not operator `as`

Comment: @abatishchev it's just an example. Can you give me a case when sender would be null when the button is attached to this event? I agree it should check for null to be safe.

Comment: I meant a null check not against `sender` but against `sender as Button` because the main purpose of operator `as` - reference nulling in case of wrong type, right?

Comment: I could do this by combining the above 2 code snippets like - void removeButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{ 
    string buttonId = removeButton.ClientId; //button id - ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_C4_imgRemoveControl
}
Then I could find the UserControl Id by splitting the buttonId. "C4" is my user control Id. Then I removed the user control from the aspx page.Thanks a lot for ur help Hunter.

Comment: no problem, glad you got it working... ASP.NET MVC, btw, is soooo much better than ASP.Net. If you have a chance to move to that tech, I would highly recommend it.

Answer (score 7):

I would add an event to the User Control and capture that event in the code behind.  Here's an example:

**Default.aspx Web Form:**

Register the user control:

```
<%@ Register TagPrefix="so" TagName="UserControl" Src="~/WebUserControl.ascx" %>
```

4 instances of the above control.  Note we're handling the OnRemoving event defined below:

```
    <so:UserControl ID="UserControl1" runat="server" Title="Control 1" OnRemoving="UserControl1_Removing" />
    <so:UserControl ID="UserControl2" runat="server" Title="Control 2" OnRemoving="UserControl2_Removing" />
    <so:UserControl ID="UserControl3" runat="server" Title="Control 3" OnRemoving="UserControl3_Removing" />
    <so:UserControl ID="UserControl4" runat="server" Title="Control 4" OnRemoving="UserControl4_Removing" />
```

**Default.aspx Code Behind:**

In the code behind, I handle each of the control's OnRemoving events:

```
protected void UserControl1_Removing(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    WebUserControl ctrl = (WebUserControl)sender;
    ctrl.Visible = false;
}
protected void UserControl2_Removing(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    WebUserControl ctrl = (WebUserControl)sender;
    ctrl.Visible = false;
}
protected void UserControl3_Removing(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    WebUserControl ctrl = (WebUserControl)sender;
    ctrl.Visible = false;
}
protected void UserControl4_Removing(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    WebUserControl ctrl = (WebUserControl)sender;
    ctrl.Visible = false;
}
```

**User Control Web Form:**

The web user control includes a "remove" button:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="WebUserControl.ascx.cs" Inherits="WebUserControl" %>

<fieldset>
  <legend><%=Title %></legend>
  <asp:Button ID="Button_Remove" runat="server" Text="Remove" OnClick="Button_Remove_Click" />
</fieldset>
```

**User Control Code Behind:**

Finally, here's how to code the event for the user control:

```
public partial class WebUserControl : System.Web.UI.UserControl
{
    // the event delegates may listen for
    public event EventHandler Removing;
    public string Title { get; set; }

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    }

    protected void Button_Remove_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // raise the event for attached delegates
        if (Removing != null)
            Removing(this, EventArgs.Empty);
    }
}
```

**Final Result:**

The above example produces the following web page.  When a remove button is clicked, that control disappears:

[image: Final product]

Good luck!!

Answer (score 0):

An easy way: have the user control implement a RemoveClicked event.  Then, when the delete button is clicked, in the button click event handler, fire the RemoveClicked event.  The page can know which user control the remove request came from.  You can even pass the button through the event args too, if you like.  The page would have to attach to this event for all 4 user controls too, FYI.

This advice assumes you are looking for a server-side solution, not a client side one.

HTH.